# Linear approximation question where f(x) = g'(x) - how to use formula?

Tags: linear-approximation

I'm a little confused by this question:

> Lines and things that are linear are relatively boring in mathematics. What
>       if my function f(x) = g'(x). I’m going to ask the same question in a
>       different way.
>
> 2. What is an approximate value of g'(1.1)?

So I know $L(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$

If I substitute items in, I get $g'(x) + g''(x)(x-x)$.

Since $x-x = 0$ I always am going to end up with $L(x) = g'(x)$

I don't think this can be the right answer since I know the whole point is to use the 2nd derivative, but if you get $0$ for $(x-a)$, then the whole part ends up being $0$. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I'm completely lost here because these are the followup question after the one above:

> Now things are interesting. Suppose g(1) = 0 and g'(1) = 1.
>
> 3. Use linear approximation to approximate the value of g(1.1).
>              The answer to #2 and #3 gives us a slope of a tangent line and a value of a function, which we can use.
> 4. Use your previous answers to approximate the value of g(1.2).
>              Somehow, this second derivative has caused an adjustment to our 
>              approximation.
> 5. What did using the second derivative do to the approximation?
> 6. Do you believe the approximation is better or worse than our original?
>          Why?

Also...MathJax isn't working fo me...it still is showing the $ in here

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: $g'(1.1)\approx g'(1)+g''(1)\times(1.1-1)=f(1)+f'(1)\times 0.1$

Comment: $g(1.1)\approx g(1)+g'(1)\times(1.1-1)=g(1)+f(1)\times0.1$

Comment: $g(1.1)\approx g(1)+g'(1.1)\times (1.1-1)\approx g(1)+f(1)\times0.1+f'(1)\times0.1^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner We are suposed to find values for these, not just give equations

Comment: I wasn't going to do all your work; in your edit you gave values for $g(1)$ and $g'(1)$, which could easily be plugged in to the equations I gave

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ahh!  OK got it...I guess I am just tryign to understand the whole second derivative part of what he is saying...just a little confusing to me.  Admittedly Calculus is not my most favorite subject

Comment: Why did you reproduce 2., 3., 4., 5., and 6., but not 1.?

Comment: Because 1(and 2) was an easy question that only required the use of the linear approximation formula, which I completed myself. Question 2 here was a "different way" of asking the linear approximation of f(1.1) and the subsequent questions relied on it...just was a little confused by using a second derivative.  Also...where does the 0.1 squared come in in the last formula?

Comment: to get the third formula, I substituted the first formula for $g'(1.1)$, and the result had $0.1^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The way he forms the question, I am thinking he wants us to somehow use the slope and the equation in part 4..so I know the slope is the first derivative, which would be g'(1), which equals 1. And the equation for g(1.1) ends up being g(1.1) = x-1. I know the equation for a slope is y = mx+b. I believe if I am plugging in values I get 1 = 1(1.2) +b and that makes b = -0.2. But I don't know exactly how to use this to find 1.2 from 1.1's slope and formula other than just using the linear approximation of 0.2 which I am pretty sure is not what he is looking for

Answer (score 1):

Given $g(1)=0$ and $g'(1)=1$,

$g(1.1)\approx g(1)+g'(1)(1.1-1)=0+1\times 0.1=0.1$ and

$\color{blue}{g'(1.1)\approx g'(1)+g''(1)\times (1.1-1)=1+0.1g''(1).}$

Using linear approximation, $g(1.2)\approx g(1)+g'(1)(1.2-1)=0+1\times 0.2=0.2.$

Better approximation:

$g(1.2)\approx g(1.1)+\color{blue}{g'(1.1)}(1.2-1.1)\approx 0.1 + \color{blue}{\left(1+0.1g''(1)\right)}0.1 = 0.2 + 0.01g''(1)$